# mysql: ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'mysql-native-password' is not loaded on mac

Tags: mysql, laravel, macos, installation

ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'mysql_native_(Password)' is not loaded

I wasn't prompted to set a root password during the installation and so whenever I tried to use mysql via the mysql -u root -p command. I got this error => Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'.

So I searched stack overflow and found an answer that involved setting the authentication plugin to mysql_native_password. the query looked something like this...

UPDATE user SET plugin="mysql_native_password";
However, for some reason I typed the command manually instead of copying it and I seem to have written mysql-native-password instead of mysql_native_password (stupid me!!!)

now I tried to access the mysql shell in various ways but I always get the following error!

ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'mysql-native-password' is not loaded

Tried with safe mode : sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
also happens to be the same problem ,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zEm0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this it worked for me ,

```
brew remove mysql
 
brew cleanup
 
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
 
rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
 
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql
```

then install mysql back